# Convert csv to json using PHP and sort

Tags: php, json, csv

Hi i'm trying to convert a CSV file to json i've managed to do it, however i'm trying to display in a certain, i.e a multi-dimentional array and then potentional sort in a certain way by an element. Can someone help me out please its like i'm hitting a dead end with this one thanks...
Here's the data I am converting...

```
100  AAA     "Random product AAA."   "28"    SHOE_EU
101  AAA     "Random product AAA."   "22"    SHOE_EU
```

I want to display the json like so...

```
   {
 "PLU": "ABC",
 "name": "Vision Windrush",
 "sizes": [
 {
 "SKU": "101",
 "size": "9"
   },
   {
   "SKU": "100",
   "size": "11"
   },
   {
  "SKU": "109",
  "size": "12"
  }
  ]
  }
```

Here's the code that I implemented...

```
  $file="product2.csv";
  $csv= file_get_contents($file);
  $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
  $array[] = json_encode(array(
                          'PLU:' => 1,
                          'name:' => 2,
                          'sizes:' => array(
                          'SKU:' => 0,
                          'size:' => 3,
                          'sizeSort:'=> 4))
                                            ,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
             print_r($array);
```

Comment: What is you CSV delimiter?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it - can you please help?

Comment: Of course, just tell me what is your CSV delimiter or add a portion of the file to the question !

Comment: yh sorry the delimeter is a comma I think however what I did is use 'str_getcsv' as a callback in the 'array_map' to to parse the CSV file into an array from the csv file and in the 'explode' function the '\n' might be it.

Comment: yo can someone please help me out?